# Pasar Variables de JavaScript a Php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Bueno quiero pasar una variable de js a otro documento php me dijieron que lo mas practico es usando ajax, pero creo que algo no esta bien :/
quiero pasar la variable de un documento .js a uno .php.
al pasar la variable no la detecta en el php, y no se si estoy haciendo un buen uso con el ajax.

```js
function showScore()
{
   $("#scoreboard").css("display", "block");
   setBigScore(true);
  
   if(score > highscore)
   {
     
      highscore = score;
    
      setCookie("highscore", highscore, 999);
   }
//AQUI COMIENZO A PASAR LA "VARIABLE"
    var elscorebest = score;
      $.ajax({
                data:  {score:elscorebest},
                url:   'ACTIONSCORE.php',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (response) {
                        if (response === 'SI') window.location = "../Juegos/GamLocker/index.php";
                }
        });
```

y esto es lo que hace mi php

```html
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['id']) {
$idder = $_SESSION['id'];
$varscore = $_POST['score'];
require("connect_db.php");
$veri=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='".$idder."' ", $link);

  if($veri==true){
      $sql = "UPDATE users SET criptcoins='$varscore' WHERE id='$idder'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql); 
     die($varscore);
      header("location: ../index.php");
  }else{
    echo '<script>alert("MAL NO DETECTA SESSION")</script>';
echo "<script>location.href='../index.php#error de pasar db'</script>";  
  }

     
   }else{
 echo '<script>alert("Ingresa Sesion")</script>';
echo "<script>location.href='../index.php#error de sesion'</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Y el error es...?

Comment: faltan partes del codigo php. fijate de poner todas las partes faltantes.

Comment: Guz el error es de la parte al pasar la variable no la detecta en el php, y no se si estoy haciendo un buen uso con el ajax.

Comment: has intentado usar `var_dump($_POST);` para saber si están los datos efectivamente?

Comment: Veo que usas "score"  pero no veo dónde le asignas un valor. Quizá sí la estás enviando a PHP pero con valor null. Una cosa es que no envíe (undefined index in $_POST) y otra que te aparezca como null o cadena vacía

Answer (score 1):

posibles soluciones:

1) verifica el valor de la variable `var elscorebest` que no sea vacia

2) intenta con `method : 'POST',` y tambien te falto especificar el tipo de dato `dataType    : 'json'`

```
var request = $.ajax({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url    : 'ACTIONSCORE.php',
                    data:  {score:elscorebest},
                    dataType    : 'json' 
                });
```

una buena practica es capturar los errores, te dejo un ejemplo, insertalo debajo de la llamada ajax

```
request.done(function(response) { 
                    if(response.status) {
                        alert('Success: ' + response.result + "\n Message: " + response.message);

                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    }
                });

                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Server request failed: " + textStatus);
                    window.location.href = '';
                });
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tiene que ser json? Creo que el OP solo quiere enviar texto plano (SÍ/NO).

Comment: Esa es una buena forma y json para porder enviar los datos bien parseados .

Comment: He estado checando el error que me lanza ahora con el request.fail pero no se que pueda ser solo me salta el request.fail la variable elscorebest no esta varía me da el valor de otra variable que uso, pero cree esa variable elscorebest para no perderme.

Comment: method y type es lo mismo... y dataType es el formato para recibir no para enviar...[+ info](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)